# EDITAR COMBO EN PHP CON BASE DE DATOS

Tags: php, visual-studio, postgresql

Estoy trabajando con php en visual studio, tengo un formulario, donde uno de esos campos en un combox, los datos de ese combo los traigo de una base de datos en postgres.

El problema esta en cuando hago el edit de los datos ingresados en el formulario, no me trae el dato que se ingreso en el combo y no se como traerme el resto por si se quiere cambiar lo ya ingresado.

El codigo del editar es este:

```
                   <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="">Tipo de lacteo</label>
                   <select name="producto_tipo" id="producto_tipo"  class="form-control " >
                   @foreach ($venta as $ventas)

                  <option value="{{ $ventas['producto_tipo']}}">{{ $ventas['producto_tipo']}}

                    </option>
                        @endforeach
                   </select> 
                 </div>
               </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes verificar que el valor de objeto sea exactamente null ya que estas usando el operador de desigualdad estricta por lo que si en vez de null tu objecto es undefined, el operador de desiguandad estricta dara como resultado true, por ejemplo:

```
obj=undefined;
obj != null // resultara falso
obj !== null //resultara verdadero
```

Recuerda que los operadores de comparacion estricta validan tanto que el valor como el tipo de dato sean iguales.

, saludos.